# If condition inside onclick attribute for input tag for WHMCS cart

Tags: php, input, onclick, smarty, whmcs

I am editing this with new information to clarify my question.

I have the following code. This is in smarty language which is used by WHMCS.

{if $errormessage}{$LANG.clientareaerrors}

  {$errormessage}

{elseif $promotioncode && $rawdiscount eq "0.00"}{$LANG.promoappliedbutnodiscount}{/if}

The section which is important is "$promotioncode && $rawdiscount eq "0.00"

So in my input box I want to run the applypromo and if the condition is not valid it shows an alert ('The coupon is not valid for this product') to be shown.

What I want to do is checking whether the promocode is associated with the chosen product and if it is not it shows a message. I checked some other carts which they do that and it has a piece of code which is similar to this:

This is used for our program which is in smarty language (WHMCS). Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Comment: you have errors in your second source code example. see " symbols in onclick

Answer (score 2):

Why not placing the `if` inside the event handler and passing an argument to it from PHP (as you requested in comments)?:

```
<a onclick="return handler(<?php echo $type;?>)" ...
```

Javascript:

```
function handler1() {
    // do something
}


function handler2() {
    // do something else
}

// this one is called
function handler(type) {
    if(type === 1) {
        handler1();
    } else if($type === 2) {
        handler2();
    } else {
        alert('Bad type: ' + type);
    }
    // return false(!) otherwise your browser will go and visit the cliked link's 
    // target url too. (thanks @DarkSide)
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not placing inside of the handler itself because the condition comes from a PHP variable, not a JS variable.

Comment: just don't forget to add `return false` in onclick event of <a> (link). Otherwise your browser will go and visit that link too.

Comment: @DarkSide Thank you! I rarely do frontend stuff since years, but you are right!

Answer (score 1):

```
<span onclick="if(condition){do_foo();}else{do_bar();}return false;">
    click me
</span>
```

Comment: This works only if the condition is a JS variable, not a PHP variable.

Comment: ah, then that's even simpler. just output from PHP what you want based on your PHP condition. Where's the problem then I don't get that :)

Comment: The problem is that the OP doesn't have a lot of experience coding in PHP/JS.

Comment: Now I get that :) Question was to simple for >10 year exp. with PHP. Sorry :)

Comment: Looks good.. Didn't recognized that you gave an answer too. :)

Answer (score 1):

So your question is really about smarty template language then.

I believe you can use the smarty ternary syntax:

```
<input type="submit" value="Apply" onclick="{($promocode=="DEMO")?'function1()':'function2()'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<input type="submit" value="Apply" onclick="<?= ($promocode === 'DEMO') ? 'function1();' : 'function2();' ?>" />`

Comment: Better don't use short PHP labels like <? and <?= :) But this example as such is correct.

Comment: @DarkSide - actually, the PHP echo tag is back in style.

Comment: @adeneo Darkside was recommending to use the echo tag.  Reason being that shorttags aren't always enabled on all servers, I presume.  My guess, however, looking at the OP's code, is that the OP doesn't really care about writing portable code.

Comment: and I noted that `<?=` (it's called an echo tag, cause that's what it does) is always available and recommended since PHP 5.4

Comment: Oh, that's great. I'm still mostly using PHP 5.3 so trying to not use shorttags.

Comment: @adeneo My bad, got confused by your terminology.  I haven't ever heard `<?=` referred to as an "echo tag."  It's typically called a "short tag."

Comment: It is a shorttag, and shorttags are not reccomended, with the exception of the echo short tag, which as previously mentioned is back in style.

Comment: Good to know... even though I don't write PHP anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick = "function() {
if(condition) { 
//do something 
}
else if(condition) { 
//do something else
}
}"
```

It is however always better practice to listen for events in the code of your javascript file than to include it as an onclick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Apply" data-prom="$promocode" 
onclick=if{ this.dataset.prom =="DEMO"}"function1();{else}function2();" />
```

if you want bind some data from back end into element and use it in the front end

you can use data-* attribute and get it with this.dataset.*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset

http://jsfiddle.net/G4qWb/ here is a little demo you can use